# Putting conditional statements inside static class in C#

Tags: c#

I have a below class:

```
public static class AllAcess
{
    public static int var1;

    //Some conditional statements
    if(somecondition)
    {
        var1 = x;
    }
    else
    {
        var1 = y;
    }
}
```

How can i put some conditional statement inside class. 
Currently it's not allowing if ,else etc .

Please suggest logic which can be used as condition here.

I want to access var1 from other classes.

Comment: You can't.  That has to go inside a method...

Comment: your `var1` should have a type

Comment: Yes,missed int ..

Comment: It's a `static` class having a `static` member. So nothing stops you using `public static int var1 = (somecondition) ? 15 : 10;` to initialize member. But I agree solution provided by @canton7 is more appropriate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors):

```
public static class AllAcess
{
    public static int var1;

    static AllAcess()
    {
        if (somecondition)
        {
            var1 = x;
        }
        else
        {
            var1 = y;
        }
    }
}
```

This is run at some point before `var1` is accessed for the first time.

Note, **do not** do anything too complicated in a static constructor. Do not do anything which touches the filesystem or network, or does any threading.

Comment: Thanks a lot @canton7

Comment: This answer could be improved by including *why* doing complicated things in the static constructor is a bad idea. I assume the reason is that static constructors don't run at well-controlled points of program execution, but are invoked automatically by the runtime.

Comment: @Joe there's probably a good answer to link to somewhere - it's a slightly involved topic, and doesn't directly address the OP's question